# Checking that a file on an HTTP server is different than a local copy

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm sure that this must have been figured out a million times already, which is why I'm asking.

I fetch files (JSON, PNG, XML, plist) from an HTTP server and save them locally.  Then these files are read, processed and displayed. My issue is that I want to know if there is a newer file on the server when I am about to proceed to a screen that will be displaying the downloaded data.  In that case, I'd like to get the file, store it and use that info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the "If-Modified-Since" http header and check the response code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are good answers out there already.  Just took some creative thinking on how to find them!

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/server-communication/how-to-download-a-file-only-if-it-has-been-updated

Great stuff.